# Is it possible to make a sub-array that updates the main array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Say I have a main array: `Arr3D(1 to 4, 1 to 4, 1 to 50)` and I want to pass over a single subset to a procedure and have that procedure edit the values. I know I can create a sub-array: `Arr(1 to 50)` and pass over the values, run the procedure, and then put them back into Arr3D.

But VBA's ability to have parameters passed into procedures "ByRef" has me thinking there might be an ability that I'm not aware of to pass a sub-Array "ByRef".

Like I want to pass over `Arr3D(1, 2, 1 to 50)` into `Sub DoStuff(ByRef Arr1D() as Variant)` so that the procedure can directly edit the values of the main array.

This is really all just to avoid having to pass the indexes and because I think it looks cleaner, I know I can just pass over the full array and just plug in `D1 = 1, D2 = 2` like `Arr3D(D1, D2, x)`.

Is this possible in VBA and how would I write it? If not, what is the best practice in VBA for running procedures on parts of arrays?

VBasic2008 asked for an example, so I made the thing I'm envisioning:

```vb
Const Directory = "\\192.168.2.253\Forms\Ingredient Inventory\Entries\"
Sub Example()
'GETTING ALL DATA FROM INPUT ENTRY FILES

    Dim oFolder As Object, oFile As Variant, Files() As Object, file_count As Integer
    Dim app As New Excel.Application, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim FileData() As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").getfolder(Directory)
    ReDim Files(oFolder.Files.Count)
    
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If oFile.Name Like "*.xls?" Then
            Set Files(file_count) = oFile
            file_count = file_count + 1
        End If
    Next oFile
    
    ReDim Preserve Files(file_count - 1)
    ReDim FileData(file_count - 1)
    
    For i = LBound(Files) To UBound(Files)
        Set wb = app.Workbooks.Add(Files(i).Path)
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        FileData(i) = ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow, 49).Value
        wb.Close savechanges:=false
    Next i
    app.Quit
    set app = Nothing
'END OF INPUT

'INTERPRET DATA
    For i = LBound(FileData, 1) To UBound(FileData, 1)
        For j = LBound(FileData, 2) To UBound(FileData, 2)
            If FileData(i, j, 4) <> "" And FileData(i, j, 5) <> "" Then
                Call InputFormattedDate(FileData(i, j))
            End If
            'Other Stuff
        Next j
    Next i
'END OF INTERPRET

'OUTPUT DATA

    'Do Stuff
    
'END OF OUTPUT
End Sub

Sub InputFormattedDate(ByRef ArrRow() As Variant)
    'ArrRow is a One Dimenion array from 1 to 49
    'I wish ArrRow could be referenced like ArrRow(4) or ArrRow(6) instead of ArrRow(D1,D2,4)
    Dim MachineNumber As String
    MachineNumber = Replace(ArrRow(4), "#", "")
    For i = 6 To 10
        'For Seperated Columns on output
        If CStr(i) = MachineNumber Then
            ArrRow(35 + i) = Text_to_Date(ArrRow(5))
        Else
            ArrRow(35 + i) = "[BLANK]" 'to overwrite previous column values
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Slicing 3D arrays without looping the indexes is not possible  AFAIK.

Comment: [`ByRef` is irrelevant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-argument-must-be-byref) btw.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Maybe add the code where you want to use it and add a line of pseudo-code how you mean to use it.

Comment: @chrisneilsen what about 2D arrays?

Comment: @VBasic2008 untested sample code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "main" array contains *values*, then a slice of that array would be *another array* containing *copies* of these *values*, and the fact that arrays are passed by reference has no bearing or implications whatsoever on this. So no, altering *values* inside a "sub-array" (which is a separate/distinct array holding *copies* of the original values)  isn't going to affect the content of the "main" array.

*Because it's holding values instead of references*.

You could make it hold *references* instead, and then you'd have a separate/distinct array holding copies of *pointers* to the original *objects*.

Add a new class module and name it `WrappedVariant`, and make it look like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private EncapsulatedValue As Variant

'@DefaultMember
Public Property Get Value() As Variant
    Value = EncapsulatedValue
End Property

Public Property Let Value(ByVal RHS As Variant)
    EncapsulatedValue = RHS
End Property
```

Where `'@DefaultMember` is a [Rubberduck annotation](https://rubberduckvba.com/Annotations/Details/DefaultMember) that controls the value of the procedure's hidden `VB_UserMemId` attribute, making it `0` (thus making the member the class' *default member*; you don't need Rubberduck to do this, it's just much, much simpler with).

Now you can do this:

```
Dim v As WrappedVariant
Set v = New WrappedVariant
v.Value = 42 'or just v = 42 for an implicit default member call
Debug.Print v.Value 'or just Debug.Print v for an implicit default member call
```

And then `v` can be stored in a 3D array that's later sliced into a smaller 2D array, and while that will be a completely unrelated separate array, the object pointers in it will still be pointing to the `WrappedVariant` object instances, each encapsulating their respective value: if you modify one specific instance using any copy of the pointer, it modifies the single object being pointed to no matter which array the pointer came from.

Remember to use the `Set` keyword to explicitly assign the *reference* - omitting `Set` (or using an explicit `Let`) would coerce the object into its value through an implicit default member call:

```
Dim array1(1 To 1)
Set array1(1) = v

Dim array2(1 To 1)
Set array2(1) = v

array1(1).Value = 25 '<~ mutate the encapsulated state from either pointer
Debug.Print array1(1), array2(1) '<~ prints 25 twice
```

That said, you'll still need to implement your own array-slicing nested loops.

Comment: I have yet to use classes in VBA and this seems like a great reason to start.